# Setting headers on redirected external URL

Tags: jsf, redirect, http-headers, jsf-2.2

Is it possible that a jsf application can navigate to an external link and specify headers for that external link?
So far I have tried to call in the backing bean method:

```
ExternalContext#setResponseHeader(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String value)
ExternalContext#redirect(java.lang.String url)
```

The redicection is successfully executed but the Headers are lost.
Is there any way to specify a link accompanied with the headers?

Answer (score 1):

No, HTTP doesn't allow setting headers on a different request.

The headers have to be set by the code behind the target URL. [Whatever problem you incorrectly thought to solve this way has definitely to be solved differently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: So how to set them to the target url? Is it by using URLConnection? Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Read the next paragraph in the answer. Just ask a new question about that *"whatever problem you incorrectly thought to solve this way"*. This problem is nowhere stated in the current question.

Comment: This is in fact my problem! I have been asked to build a web page which will serve defining a url and a bunch of http headers  that will be sent to that url (user inputs). So the app will call this url with the headers

Comment: But you didn't ask that. You asked how to navigate (redirect) to an external link and set headers on that other request. If you have a new question, just ask that. Be careful to ask about how to approach/solve a problem instead of how to get a wrong solution working without telling anything about the problem you tried to solve with the wrong solution. Again, see that link in my answer.

Comment: Two (almost) identical uncommon questions in 1 day... Sounds like some students got an assignment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624101/setting-http-headers-to-target-url

Comment: @Kukeltje: or a colleague working on same project, or a sockpuppet for votes, or a second account to circumvent question rate limit, or a genuinely curious user who saw the current question and is interested in the "real" answer too  and decided to ask on own. I really couldn't care. This is up to the moderators. You can always flag and mention the suspicious relationship so that mods can eventually figure out it.