# Setting HTTP headers to target url

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have been asked to build an web-app which will have a page where the user can define the url he wants to navigate to (which is an external link) and add additional http headers he can send with that url. The web-app will be build with jsf 2.1
Which headers exactly do you need to set and what exactly are they for? 
Answ: They are additional headers H-Version,H-UniqueID etc.

Is it a specific or an arbitrary external URL? 
Answ: is an specific url (but it must be absolute)

And, importantingly, what exactly does the first response of a request on that external URL represent? Does it represent a full blown HTML page (thus with all relative references on it such as CSS/JS/images/links), or does it return a special response (e.g. XML/JSON or even a simple HTTP redirect)?
Answ: The target link will call another java-web-app which it's response will be html/CSS/JS/images/links..

Do you guys know any solution for this,
Many thanks!

Comment: There's still too much ambiguity here. Which headers exactly do you need to set and what exactly are they for? Is it a specific or an arbitrary external URL? And, importantingly, what exactly does the first response of a request on that external URL represent? Does it represent a full blown HTML page (thus with all relative references on it such as CSS/JS/images/links), or does it return a special response (e.g. XML/JSON or even a simple HTTP redirect)?

Comment: I've never seen a requirement like this. Are you sure you cannot pass the key-value pairs as request headers?

Comment: Two (almost) identical uncommon questions in 1 day... Sounds like some students got an assignment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618002/setting-headers-on-redirected-external-url

Comment: It's the same person who forgot the email of the previous account and now is using an older one..no intention to compete as stackoverflow guru..just seeking for a solution. Thanks ;)